# webKit not loading page

Tags: ios, swift, webkit, wkwebview

I have been attempting to load a webpage in iOS to no avail. I have used the same code on other view controllers in the project but all it shows for this page is the blank white screen. Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController { 
    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear( animated )

        let url:URL = URL(string: "http://www.fairburyjeffs.org")!
        let urlRequest:URLRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
        webView.load(urlRequest)
    }
```

Comment: put ats in info.plist ???

Comment: I tried this to no avail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code are working fine as you wanted to-

[image]
The reason i found behind this -

1. If you try https://www.google.com/ . It will work in one RUN. 
   But when you run it with your `url` it won't. Why? because the 
   difference of `http` and `https`. For more you can read the Apple 
   documentations.

   You just need to do the following steps-

   - Open your Info.plist file of your project. Right click on it and add a row.

[image]

And after that just add those two lines in your `Info.plist` (as it is) -

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to load an HTTP url (i.e "http://www.fairburyjeffs.org") so make sure that you have set Arbitary Loads to YES in info.plist. If you don't set Arbitary Loads to YES, the http pages won't load.

[image: App transport Security Settings and Allowing Arbitrary loads]